# What I'm doing wrong? "responsive page"

Tags: css

I have a container and wallpaper inside a page.
What I'm trying to do is to resize the container and the wallpaper to mach any device screen size.

**I have managed to make the wallpaper working, but the container doesnt work for me.
What I'm doing wrong?**

This is my code:

```
html,body{height:100%}
#left-link {
position: fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
z-index:99;
width:auto;
height:auto;
}

#container {
width:500px;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:10px;
position:relative;
z-index:100;
}

body {
margin: 30px 0 0 0;
background: url(https://example.com/.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: You seem to hard-coded the container to remain 500px at every viewport width.

Comment: oh :D! okay you can post it as an answer, it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container is set at 500px, which is a set size. If you want it to be responsive, set it to a percentage such as `50%`, which would be half of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have hard-coded the container to remain 500px at every viewport width.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by the more general solution of *never* using absolute units for anything.

Anything like "px", "in", "cm" are absolute units and should be avoided.

Instead use relative units:  "em" (or if you must, "rem") when legibility is the main concern (e.g. reading some lettering in an image); and "%" (or "vh" and "vw") when overall layout is the main concern.

Your example has "500px", "10px", and "30px".

It would be more "responsive" if instead it had, say "90%", ".5em", and "4%".

And to make things fit into containers the way you would expect them to:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```